# Converting Nanoseconds to Datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm having a little trouble converting nanoseconds to `DateTime` so i can use the Google Fit API (https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/datasets/get)

> Dataset identifier that is a composite of the minimum data point start
>   time and maximum data point end time represented as nanoseconds from
>   the epoch. The ID is formatted like: "startTime-endTime" where
>   startTime and endTime are 64 bit integers.

I was able to convert from datetime to Nanoseconds this way

```
DateTime zuluTime = ssDatetime.ToUniversalTime();
DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
ssNanoSeconds = (Int32)(zuluTime.Subtract(unixEpoch)).TotalSeconds + "000000000";
```

But now i need to convert nanoseconds to `DateTime`. How can i do it?

Comment: `Ticks` resolution is 100 nanoseconds. You can add it with `AddTicks` method.

Comment: Nanoseconds since when? 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z or some time else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [AddTicks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addticks(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Don't forget to divide nanoseconds by 100 to get ticks.

```
long nanoseconds = 1449491983090000000;
DateTime epochTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime result = epochTime.AddTicks(nanoseconds / 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) property represents 100 nanoseconds. So how about :

```
 var ssNanoSeconds = ((zuluTime.Subtract(unixEpoch)).Ticks / 100)
```

From nanoseconds to DateTime

```
 DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddTicks(nanoSeconds * 100) ;
```

Comment: Your `new DateTime` is starting with `DateTime.MinValue`, not the unix epoch.

Comment: Also the nanoSeconds in the first line need to be multiplied by 100 and divided in the second example.
so: `..(zuluTime.Subtract(unixEpoch)).Ticks * 100 ..`
and `.AddTicks(nanoSeconds / 100)`

Answer (score 0):

To convert nanoseconds to a DateTime object, you can do the following:

Divide the nanoseconds value by 1,000,000,000 to get the equivalent number of seconds.
Create a DateTime object representing the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970).
Add the number of seconds to the Unix epoch to get the desired DateTime object.

```
long nanoseconds = 1234567890123; // nanoseconds value to convert

// Divide the nanoseconds value by 1,000,000,000 to get the equivalent number of seconds
int seconds = (int)(nanoseconds / 1000000000);

// Create a DateTime object representing the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970)
DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

// Add the number of seconds to the Unix epoch to get the desired DateTime object
DateTime datetime = unixEpoch.AddSeconds(seconds);
```

Note that this will only work correctly if the nanoseconds value is within the range of values that can be represented by a DateTime object (approximately 292 million years before or after the Unix epoch). If the nanoseconds value is outside of this range, the resulting DateTime object will not be accurate.